# Delphi: Keyboard shortcut to create a new UNIT?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

In the Delphi 10.3.3 IDE, is there a keyboard shortcut to create a new UNIT? Or is it possible to create such a keyboard shortcut?

Going over File -> New is too cumbersome.

Comment: Isn't the most top left icon (directly beneath the ,``File`` menu) for creating a new unit (I don't have an IDE at hand at the moment)? I know that's no keyboard shortcut, but faster to reach than clicking through the menu.

Comment: @DelphiCoder No, for me it's "View Unit". The only "New" one is a few icons over "New Items" which pops up a dialog to choose what type of new item to create. Surely not any easier. Plus the position of these can be customized.

Comment: @JerryDodge Thank you to make this more clear

Comment: I was about to suggest using the GExperts IDE Menu Shortcuts expert, but unfortunately it turned out that it does not support those menu items the IDE adds dynamicall, which are all configurable entries under File -> New, including File -> New -> Unit

Comment: There also seems to be no 'Create new unit' command to be placed on a toolbar in the CUSTOMIZE dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the main menu allows using `ALT` shortcuts, you could do:

> ALT + F, N, U

That quickly selects File > New > Unit.

Comment: I've already tried that. But it should be a single action keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @user1580348 Then I guess you're out of luck. That's the quickest keyboard shortcut that seems to be possible.

Comment: You can create a single purpose key mapping wizard. ToolsAPI itself provides ways to create new modules.

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows a minimal IDE plug-in which uses the OTA to add a hot-key
to open a new unit.  As shown, it is activated using Ctrl-Alt-U.

The way it works is to use OTA services to access the IDE's main menu and adds
a new menu entry - captioned MyAdded for ease of identifcation - which, if visible
(and it doesn't have to be) would appear to the right of `Help` in the IDE's main menu.

This added menu entry has Ctrl-Alt-U as its shortcut.  Its OnClick handler, `MyAddedClick`, executes the
method `ClickNewUnit`, which iterates the File | New submenu to find the `Unit - Delphi` MenuItem
and calls its `Click`Method, causing the IDE to create and open a new unit.

Add the unit below to a new .DPK file named NewUnit.Dpk, compile it then use Component | Install Packages
to install.

```
unit NewUnitu;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, ToolsAPI, Menus;

type
  TNewUnit = class
  private
    procedure ClickNewUnit(Sender: TObject);
  public
    //Services: IOTAServices;
    IntaServices : INTAServices40;
    ModServices: IOTAModuleServices;
    Module : IOTAModule;
    AddedMenuItem : TMenuItem;
    MainMenu : TMainMenu;
    procedure MyAddedClick(Sender : TObject);
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  NewUnit: TNewUnit;
 [...]

constructor TNewUnit.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  //Services := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAServices;  not needed
  IntaServices := BorlandIDEServices as INTAServices40;
  Assert(IntaServices <> Nil);

  MainMenu := IntaServices.GetMainMenu;

  AddedMenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(Nil);
  AddedMenuItem.Caption := 'MyAdded';
  AddedMenuItem.ShortCut := 49237;  // = Ctrl-Alt-U
  AddedMenuItem.OnClick := MyAddedClick;
  //  AddedMenuItem.Visible := False;
  MainMenu.Items.Add(AddedMenuItem);
end;

destructor TNewUnit.Destroy;
begin
  MainMenu.Items.Remove(AddedMenuItem);
  AddedMenuItem.Free;
  //Services := Nil;
  IntaServices := Nil;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TNewUnit.ClickNewUnit(Sender : TObject);
var
  MenuItem : TMenuItem;
  AMenuItem : TMenuItem;
  i,
  j,
  k : Integer;
  Done : Boolean;
begin
 // ShowMessage('In click new unit'); exit;    for debugging
  Done := False;
  for i := 0 to MainMenu.Items.Count - 1 do begin
    MenuItem := MainMenu.Items[i];
    if Pos('file', LowerCase(MenuItem.Caption)) > 0 then begin
      AMenuItem := MenuItem;
      for j := 0 to AMenuItem.Count - 1 do begin
        for k := 0 to AMenuItem.Items[j].Count - 1 do begin
          if Pos('unit', LowerCase(MenuItem.Items[j].Items[k].Caption)) > 0 then begin
            MenuItem.Items[j].Items[k].Click;
            Done := True;
            Break;
          end;
        end;
        if Done then Break;
      end;
    end;
    if Done then Break;
  end;
end;

procedure TNewUnit.MyAddedClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClickNewUnit(Sender);
end;

initialization

  NewUnit := TNewUnit.Create;

finalization

  NewUnit.Free;

end.
```

Caveats

- This was written and tested in Delphi 10.2.2 Seattle, because I don't have Rio installed.
- It works fine provided a code-editor window is open at the time Ctrl-Alt-U is pressed. It would be more robust if it checked that  there is s code-editor window open and, if not, opens one.

Comment: Works perfectly under Rio. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such shortcut.  The alternative is to right-click the project -> `Add New` -> `Unit`.

There are third-party addons like GExperts or CnPack that add macro capabilities to the IDE allowing you to automate many such tasks but this is not in-built in the vanilla IDE.  You could also write your own custom IDE extension using the [Open Tools API](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Extending_the_IDE_Using_the_Tools_API).

Comment: A macro is not a keyboard shortcut. And as the vanilla IDE does not have an explicit menu item to create a new unit, it is not possible to customize that menu item with GExperts IDE Menu Shortcuts.

Comment: @user1580348 I used those two as examples - I don't know whether they can do what you want, I'm just using them to show that third-party IDE add-ons exist and can potentially add such functionality.  Giving specific recommendations for third-party tools is off-topic here anyway, so it's more just to show you want your options are.